Maintenance of Yamaha YDP-140 Digital piano
I own a Yamaha YDP-140 Digital piano (here the link to the series, my model is no longer manufactured but it's very similar to the newer ones).
It works fine but it has two major issues I'm going to repair, if possible:

the sustain pedal has lost its original sensitivity: now to achieve a full-pedal I have to press a lot with my foot, just a lack of pressure will switch back to half-pedal

some keys exibith a weird sound when released, like there is something the moves or bounces internally


I'm quite good at DIY and I'm going to try to fix those issues by myself.
Is there anyone who has experience and could tell me how to do it?

Have you tried to get the service manuals directly from Yamaha? That's often the best place to start, especially when dealing with a long-established manufacturer producing all kinds of serviceable products.

My experience with this kind of things is mixed. Sometimes easy, sometimes destroying things more than fixing. The pedal is probably only some metal spring to bend. The keys might be the counterweights that are loose - a bit of the right glue might help. But as mentioned, it can go wrong.

From the website manualslib.com, Yamaha music section, I found a service manual for YDP-131 which has disassembly instructions (with pictures) in both English and Japanese.  Hope this helps.

@GratefulDisciple, Theodore, I didn't know there is such a manual for commercial products like these. Thank you
